# How can I get my text to hug around the top of my image?

Tags: css, css-float, css-shapes

I have been working around with the new adobe `CSS Shapes` and to no avail, sadly.

Since my browser only supports 20%(should still support what I'm using) I figured I would start to work around this and try something new.

I am trying to have the image in the center of the text and have the text hug the image from the top. If you add a `margin-top` to the `#circle-left`/`#cirlce-right` you will see just blank space above the image, here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3AQ4G/1/).

**If you want to try out `CSS Shapes` then click this [link](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/enable/) and follow the steps to enable them on your browser.**

> This section is not normative.
>
> Shapes define arbitrary geometries that can be used as CSS values.
>   This specification defines properties to control the geometry of an
>   element’s float area. The shape-outside property uses shape values to
>   define the float area for a float.
>
> Note: Future levels of CSS Shapes will allow use of shapes on elements
>   other than floats. Other CSS modules can make use of shapes as well,
>   such as CSS Masking [CSS-MASKING] and CSS Exclusions
>   [CSS3-EXCLUSIONS].
>
> Note: If a user agent implements both CSS Shapes and CSS Exclusions,
>   the shape-outside property defines the exclusion area for an
>   exclusion.
>
> Note: A future level of CSS Shapes will define a shape-inside
>   property, which will define a shape to wrap content within the
>   element.

I have achieved my desired effect in every way except I am unable to get my text to wrap above the image/container. I have used `margin`, `padding`, `top`, and positioned it `relative`.

Here is my `CSS`, ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cggs8/3/))

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#circle-left {
    shape-outside: circle(50% 50% 50%); /* CSS Shapes, my browser is not supporting this sadly */
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: -100px;
}

#circle-right {
    shape-outside: circle(50% 50% 50%);
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -100px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

Is there anyone out there that knows about `CSS Shapes` or how I could go about this? I would like to keep it only to css but if javascript is needed I'll give it a try.

*I am not trying to support all browser or anything of that nature, just trying to learn the new tools adobe is working on.*

**Resources**

- [Adobe Shapes](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/shapes/)
- [W3C Part 1](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/)
- [W3C Part 2](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes-2/)

Comment: Can you explain how you mean "text to wrap above the image"? Do you want the image placed lower to have the columns hug it across the top?

Comment: @ChrisHardie I'll explain what I am trying to do. I am trying to have the image in the center of the text and have the text hug the image as you stated. This is why I was trying to use `CSS Shapes` but my browser won't support it for some reason. If you know about `CSS Shapes` that would be amazing because that is what I was trying to learn. I am just determined to figure this out so I moved away from `CSS Shapes`.

Comment: Check out [this demo](http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/Duqdm), it uses `canvas` and CSS shapes to do some awesome stuff, you may be able to use a similar approach

Comment: [Another perhaps useful demo](http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/kuCGd)

Comment: @ZachSaucier The first demo you included is a nice option I would like to learn. The second option is spot on with `CSS Shapes` but I doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe jsfiddle doesn't support `CSS Shapes`? Should I try codepen? I would much rather have it work with `CSS Shapes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a long time, but yes. It's effectively the same idea as yours but uses zero width containers to push down the shapes.

```css
.pusher {
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100px;  /* top pos of img */
}
#left .pusher  { float: right; }
#right .pusher { float: left;  }

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.circle {
    display: block;
    width: 100px; /* half width of img */
    height: 200px; /* height of img */
}
#left .circle {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    
    -webkit-shape-outside: rectangle(
        0px,
        0,
        200px, /* width of img */
        200px, /* height of img */
        50%,
        50%
    );
}
#right .circle {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    
    -webkit-shape-outside: rectangle(
        -100px, /* 0 - width of img */
        0,
        200px, /* width of img */
        200px, /* height of img */
        50%,
        50%
    );
}

p {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" />
<p id="left">
    <span class="pusher"></span>
    <span class="circle"></span>
    Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation, eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by the classical author and philospher Cicero. It's words and letters have been changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical; it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's still resembles classical Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder
</p>
<p id="right">
    <span class="pusher"></span>
    <span class="circle"></span>
    Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation, eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by the classical author and philospher Cicero. It's words and letters have been changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical; it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's still resembles classical Latin. Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder
</p>
```

Comment: (Tested in Chrome 31, not sure about other browsers)

Comment: Very well done! This is a great option and I will mark it as the answer if I don't get anything else from some `CSS Shape` guru. I would much rather learn why they are not working but I can view the effect on other websites. Could be due to jsfiddle but I am uncertain.